# Scraping taglist using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dynamic, tags

I've been trying to scrape additional information on used vehicles from a tagpanel and i'm always getting the same information.
It's my first time using Selenium and I'm not an advanced python user, but I'm needing this info to make a research on vehicle prices.

The webpage I want to take the info from is for example:

https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-1363201661-chevrolet-tracker-18-ltz-4x2-2019-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=b0581b52-3437-4d39-b6ad-2a3ebbb053f4

The tagpanel is this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVL5J.png)

And the second tab in there is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJOXB.png)

There are almost 9 categories.

Whenever I want to download the info I only get the first answers, using:

driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec")[0].text
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec")[1].text

Alarma and Direccion Assisted are the only answers I get from the code.

I made some research and understood this are dynamic webpages, but couldn't work it out on how to select the items and then extract the info from "Información General", "Rendimiento y dimensiones", "Confort y conveniencia", etc.

I think the HTML code from that part of the webpage is:

```
<div class="andes-tabs__container"><div class="andes-tabs__scroll-tool"><div class="andes-tabs__scroll-tool--fade" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);"></div><div class="andes-tabs__scroll-tool--controls"><svg class="control-arrow control-arrow--disabled" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="#000" fill-opacity=".25" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M7.833 9.99l4.796-4.795-.849-.849-5.644 5.645 5.65 5.649.848-.849z"></path></g></svg><svg class="control-arrow" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="#000" fill-opacity=".9" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M7.428 5.195l.849-.849 5.644 5.645-5.65 5.649-.848-.849 4.801-4.8z"></path></g></svg></div></div><div class="andes-tabs__wrapper andes-tabs__wrapper--scrollable"><div class="andes-tabs" role="tablist" aria-label=""><button class="andes-tab andes-tab--full-width andes-tab--first andes-tab--selected" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-content-id-información-general" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Información general</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab andes-tab--full-width" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-confort-y-conveniencia" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Confort y conveniencia</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab andes-tab--full-width" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-rendimiento-y-dimensiones" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Rendimiento y dimensiones</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-seguridad" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Seguridad</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-exterior" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Exterior</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-entretenimiento" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Entretenimiento</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-interior" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Interior</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-seguridad" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Seguridad</span></div></button><button class="andes-tab andes-tab--last" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-content-id-condiciones-de-compra" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="andes-tab__link"><span>Condiciones de compra</span></div></button></div></div><div class="andes-tabs__border"></div><div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="tab-content-id-información-general" class="andes-tab-content"><div class="ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec"><p class="ui-pdp-family--REGULAR ui-pdp-specs__specs-list"><span class="ui-pdp-color--BLACK ui-pdp-size--XSMALL ui-pdp-family--BOLD">Dirección</span>: assisted</p></div><div class="ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec"><p class="ui-pdp-family--REGULAR ui-pdp-specs__specs-list"><span class="ui-pdp-color--BLACK ui-pdp-size--XSMALL ui-pdp-family--REGULAR">Alarma</span></p></div></div></div>
```

Hope someone can help me out with this one!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any class name "ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec" on the provided webpage

Comment: When I changed my web browser from Edge to Chrome the tagpanel changed simply to rows and columns and I was able to scrape it from there.

Comment: I really don't know why this happened. But I did a loop over the classes in this webpage and found that "andes-table__body" was repeated several times. After that I did some further research with the method .get_attribute('innerHTML') and there I saw the th class="andes-table__header andes-table__header--left ui-vpp-striped-specs__row__column ui-vpp-striped-specs__row__column--id" and span class="andes-table__column--value"

Comment: In the end I couldn't solve the problem of webscraping tagpanels but at least I did find a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well now the workaround doesn't work anymore. It'seems the HTML code frome my browser differs from the one that I get from the selenium browser. Now I'm back as in the original post, I can't get the entire information because there is a tag panel.

Comment: So when I run the code driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-pdp-specs__tabs
") I get all the different tab names (nine): Informacion, Confort y conveniencia, etc.
I've tried to click on them with driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"andes-tab")[0].click() but it doesn't work. Finally as I said before, I only can run this part o f the code driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec")[0].text driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-pdp-specs__tab-spec")[1].text